# How many undefined values do Scheme have?

Tags: scheme, undefined

I read on https://ds26gte.github.io/tyscheme/index-Z-H-11.html *tree.girth* returns "**an** undefined value". Is this right? Have Scheme really multiply undefined values?

Comment: Relevant: [Value returned by a define expression in Scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41213786/5916915)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Undefined" is not a specific value. What it's saying is that the value returned is not defined by the language specification, so it could be anything.

Some implementations may have a specific object that they return in these situations, to aid with debugging. But there's no requirement to do so. And whether different instances of these object are equal to each other is not specified -- it's not like `#false`, which is always the same object.

Answer (score 1):

`Undefined` means that you must not use the return value -- it can be anything.

In *scheme* a command like `display` will return the `#!unspecific` symbol and in *racket*(i.e. the old *plt-scheme*) the `void` symbol.  You should not use the value `#!unspecific` returned by `display`.  This means  `undefined` value.

```
% mit-scheme
MIT/GNU Scheme running under GNU/Linux
Type `^C' (control-C) followed by `H' to obtain information about interrupts.

Copyright (C) 2019 Massachusetts Institute of Technology

1 ]=> (display (display "ok"))
ok#!unspecific
;Unspecified return value
```

---

```
% racket
Welcome to Racket v7.3.
>  (display (display "ok"))
ok#<void>
>
```